# Execution of cmd over SSH

Tags: parameters

In my current architecture, I connect from my local script to a server in SSH, and execute a .sh script. The purpose of the script is to execute an SQL query and to output the result in a file.

My .sh script contains `mysql -h ${hostname} -P ${port} -u ${dbuser} -p${auth} ${dbname} -e "`cat ${sqlfile}`" > ${outfile}`

At this moment, I wonder if it is the right way to do it, which means having my parameters in my script in remote and just have to execute the .sh script. Or put all these parameters in my local script, execute directly the mysql command and get rid of the .sh script?

To make it more simple maybe, when I have to execute something over SSH, the parameters that I need to use to execute the command, should they be stored directly on the SSH server or do I have to store them on my local server ? And if there is no better way, what could be the pro and cons for each ?

Comment: It's impossible to say which is the right way without any context. For starters, what do these scripts actually **do**?

Comment: I know that this is not specifically tagged with "best-practice" but you might want to avoid using that term (if possible) to narrow your question or obtain the best possible solution. Check out... http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/3164/please-blacklist-best-practices

Comment: @Ixrec The purpose of the script is to execute SQL query and output the result in a file (i edited the question). Does it help you to answer?

Comment: Ah, the joys of constructing SQL safely.  https://xkcd.com/327/

Answer (score 1):

If your script only execute some sql query on remote machine, it's better you use some mysql connector from your apps and connect directly to remote mysql server.

If you want to execute more complex shell script on remote host, there is 2 tips:

1. Assign your param into your commands (every line command wich need param).
2. Send first your param collection to remote host. You can use file with json format. Send it via ssh(scp). And then you can run single script file on remote which this script load your file param which send before. Use name of file param uniqly, for example you can combine from date string.